# Get euclidean distance between colour and list of colours

Tags: numpy, scipy, scikit-image

In numpy or scipy or scikit-learn how can I find the distance between one colour and an array of colours? I know how to find the euclidean distance between 2 arrays of colours. But I simply have one colour and I want to know its euclidean distance between it and an array of colours so I can then find the 'closest' colour in that array?

The below works for 2 arrays of colours but not for 1 colour vs an array of colours:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist, euclidean
colour = (255,0,0)
colours = [(255,0,0), (255,0,0), (255,0,0)]
colour_array = [(255,255,255), (0,0,0), (255,0,0)]
dists = cdist(colour, colour_array)  # error because not same shape/dimensions
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put the single color into a one-element array and compare it to your array of colors. For instance:

```py
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

colour = (255, 0, 0)
colour_array = [(255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0)]

# Note change here.
dists = cdist([colour], colour_array)
```

I hope this helps!